# Should we have a canonical question about degree revocations?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

**Update: This is now [live](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153661/what-are-the-criteria-for-degree-revocation/).**

It seems like we've got a lot of questions about degree revocations recently ([1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124106/will-the-phd-degree-be-retracted-if-the-thesis-is-found-to-be-not-novel), [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123891/can-my-university-revoke-my-degree-after-it-was-granted-due-to-corporate-data), [3](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102999/can-a-department-revoke-a-degree-once-granted-by-the-university), for example).

It seems like the answer is consistently "No, unless you intentionally committed fraud (which you would know about)."

Should we create a canonical question to close all questions like these as a dupe of?

Comment: It is interesting that there have been so many lately. It may be that one has spawned the next that spawned the next and it will all die down shortly. But, yes, we should...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is already an answer someplace that could become a canonical answer.

Comment: Are there universities that are known to have significantly different practices? E.g. is there something like "If you went to X State, they occasionally revoke degrees according to general principles, if you went to State U of Y then you should know they are notorious for revoking degrees for even the most minor of irregularities like not saving your parking permit for five years beyond graduation as required by Policy Circular 22.A.ii., and if you went to Memorial U of Z, they haven't revoked a degree since 1532.", or do 99.9% of universities follow the same set of general principles on this?